# Does Flyway by Boxfuse support Db2 for i

Tags: flyway, db2-400

Flyway supports Db2 for LUW and Db2 for z/OS.  Is Db2 for i (the integrated database on AS/400, iSeries, System i)?

Comment: Please give us some more context to this question

Comment: What happened when you tried it. If it uses JDBC, then you can get the JTOpen drivers from sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Flyway only supports DB2 LUW.